# Tokens in Views don't seem to work

Tags: 7, views, tokens

I added a new view (block) with **FIELDS** type. I added "Content: Comment count" to see the comments number, and in "Rewrite results" I clicked to "Output this field as a link", and added the token "[comment_count] == Content: Comment count" as link.
This link doesn't work.

When I add a different token, such as "[body] == Content: Body" or "[title] == Content: Title," the links still don't work.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: To what do you want to link? First, only `[body]` is the token and what you should use. But you probably actually need the nid/cid token, depending what you want to link to.

Comment: Hi. I actually make it to work. I have used "Exclude from display" and somehow manage it to work like I wanted to. I still need to add some field x2 but it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Please create an answer, explain in detail what you did and accept it as an answer for this question once you can (you have to wait 24h I think). Then, the question is correctly marked as resolved and if someone else lands here with the same problem, they know how to fix it. We are trying to build a database of good questions and answers here :) Additionally, someone might give you a hint on how to solve it easier.

Comment: No problem - if u can't add token just create field the token link to and make it "Exclude from display". Then u can make use of the token it self. So if u want use token [comment_count] u need first to crate a Comment Count, and if u don't need it (don't want the text and count) just make it "Exclude from display". The rest depend of what you want to achieve. Remember that u can create some field x2 or even x3. For example u can make one link that make link from all body content and second one that make a link from comment count (first u need to create body and comment field).

Comment: @bart: You need to do that as an answer, not a comment :) There should be a blue button at the end of the page, allowing you to answer your own question. Also, I still don't really get what kind of link you are creating, it does not make any sense to me to use comment_count and similar tokens *in a link*. So, provide your actual and exact configuration as an example, if possible. You could even provide screenshots of your configuration, that would be awesome :)

Comment: Hmmm I thought I did add an answer here with screens...

Comment: @bart: You didn't.  Scroll down this page click the "Answer Your Question" button, and the fill in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do the same thing.  I had a view of blog posts and at the bottom of the post I wanted to put a link that had a comment count that was a hyperlink (as I've seen this done on many other blogs).  The way I did it was like this:

Originally my view was set up to just display the full nodes.  I clicked to edit the view and went to Page Details->FORMAT->Show and changed the setting from "Content" to "Fields".

Added the following fields:

```
Content: Title
Content: Body
Content: Path
Content: Comment count
```

The key and answer to this post is: Even though I don't want to display the path on my view I need to add it as a field so that I can later use it when building the link for the comment count.  Also I believe the order of the paths is important, so the path field must come before the comment count field.  For the `Content: Path` field I checked the "Exclude from display" check box.  This hides the path from showing up in the view. Next under "REWRITE RESULTS", I checked "Use absolute link (begins with "http://")".  This is necessary for a proper URL when using the path as token below.

For the `Content: Comment count` field, under "REWRITE RESULTS" I checked "Output this field as a link" and in the "Link path" box I put `[path]`.

Comment: The order of the fields in  your list is important as User says: If you try to user [comment_count] as a token in title, body, or path in the above list of Fields, it will not work. You need to make sure that the field you want to use as a token is BEFORE the field you want to use the token in.